# Bootstrap 3/4 Column Gutters

Tags: bootstrap-4

Okay, so when building a site using Bootstrap, you use a lot of columns such as col-md-4, col-md-3, col-md-6 etc...

When you have rows which don't use a column grid, these will always be out of line with the rest of the content because the columns create a 15px gutter each side and then you end up with a website which is out of line when you a combination of rows and rows which use columns...

What is the best practise to avoid this?

Are you supposed to use col-md-12 for anything that isn't an in a column structure or is there some awesome CSS that fixes the issue?

Let me know,

Thanks.

I will add a more details example if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `col` inside of your row, it is easiest way to avoid that

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="height: 50vh;">
            <div class="col-6 bg-primary text-center">col-6</div>
            <div class="col-6 bg-success text-center">col-6</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="height: 50vh;">
            <div class="col bg-warning text-center">col</div> <!-- Here it is -->
          </div> 
      </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```